# I think I deleted boot files, but I restored with back up. Does it still affect my computer?

Tags: boot, 20.04, mount, uefi, duplicate-files

I was trying to mount my Raspberry pi pico as **USB mass storage device** (this is what I thought that I'm doing) manually on Terminal, using the commands -

```
$ sudo mkdir -p /mnt/pico
$ sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/pico
```

After this command, I found out that in my `/mnt/pico` directory, two files, **EFI** and **System Volume Information**, had appeared. These were the same files that were already existing in `/boot/efi` directory. **I thought that the `mount` command may have copy-pasted (duplicated) those files to here**.

I felt that I did something that I'm not supposed to do. So I thought to delete these folders from the directory `/mnt/pico` as I thought that they are just **Duplicated files**. But still I made a Backup of those files (**EFI** and **System Volume Information**) in my `/home` directory.

After this, I deleted those files inside `/mnt/pico` directory. Then I was shocked as this action also removed those files from `/boot/efi` directory.

Now, with the help of backed-up folder, I copy-pasted those files again into `mnt/pico` using the command -

```
cp -a /home/myusername/boot-backup/ /mnt/pico/
```

After this command, I got many error messages, but those files were copied into `mnt/pico` directory, and these files also started to appear in the directory `/boot/efi` aswell.

Now I tried to reverse the `mount` action by -

```
sudo umount /mnt/pico
```

After this, the directory `/mnt/pico` was empty, and those files were still available in `/boot/efi` directory, as I intended them to be.

Does my actions still affect my computer in any way?

Comment: Hello. The mount command can not move files or copy them. It seems you have done some serious damage to your system, Why would you ever use commands without knowing what they do? At this point I would back up any important files and reinstall.

Comment: @David I suggest you re-read this and reconsider your advice to reinstall. A more valid comment would be “Does your system still boot without error messages”. In my answer below I’m assuming that it does since there is no comment that it doesn’t and the body of the question is full of detail.

Comment: @PonJar taken right from the question. <After this command, I got many error messages,> I suggest you read the question.

Comment: @David I did read the question and agree with you that reinstalling is a pragmatic solution if the system is unbootable. However we don’t know that. We do know that despite unspecified error messages the boot directory was restored so there is a good chance there is no enduring problem. The final sentence of the question suggests to me that the questioner is concerned that he might have broken something but that it appears to be ok.

Comment: My system booted wothout any problem, not even a delay compared to previous booting time. I also haven't faced any problem. So, as a user, I haven't faced/noticed any issue, but I'm unsure whether is there any change or issue at low level interfaces (I'm mean the level which only a programmer can understand, like some internal error messages, etc)

Comment: If all you did was what you described there is nothing to worry about. It’s worth knowing the following command `journalctl -p 3 -b 0`. This will show you any errors in your logs since you last booted. If you have any you can research them. Some are worth  fixing, some are nothing to worry about. The bottom line is that if your system is doing what you want it to in a time you are happy with all is well. You can waste many hours fine tuning or fixing things that make no material difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you have said I don’t think you have damaged your installation at all after restoration from backup. Your first mount command almost certainly mounted your system at `/mnt/pico`. That means the same files are visible in two places of the filesystem. Delete from either place deletes them from both.

Despite the name of the mount point your pico device was not mounted since it was not specified in the mount command.

If your system still boots then no harm has been done.

To mount a device you would normally identify it first using a command like `lsblk` and then use a mount command as you did but specifying the correct device